# Considering there exists a homomorphism between two rings show that a condition must exist.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-homomorphism

$R$ is defined as \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&a\end{bmatrix} such that $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ where R is a subring of all 2-by-2 matrices with integer inputs.

There exists a homomorphism $θ :R→Z$ such that $θ(R) = ra + sb$.

You are asked to prove that must $r = 1$ and $s = ± 1$.

I know the 2 points that must be satisfied for a homomorphism to happen between two rings and don't think these help to proving the question. I think you need to start with using the idea that $\ker(θ)$ is an ideal of $R$ and the $im(θ)$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Z}$. Am I right or is this wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean $\theta(A) = ra + sb$ for some $A \in R$ given by the matrix $[a, b; b, a]$?

Comment: yes I do thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assume $\theta:R\to\Bbb Z$ is a homomorphism of unital rings, mapping
$\theta\pmatrix{a&b\\b&a}=ra+sb$.

Then specifically it maps the identity element ($I=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$, i.e. when $a=1,\ b=0$) to $1$, which means $r=1$.

On the other hand, observe that for $B:=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$ we have $B^2=I$, so we must also have $\theta(B)^2=\theta(I)=1$, where $\theta(B)=s$.